# C# - Reading from CSV file producing two entries at once?

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to read in a list of several hundred thousand values from what once was a spreadsheet, but for the sake of simplicity, I have turned into a CSV file.

My problem is that while testing it to make sure it reads properly, the code is for some reason ignoring the comma after the second position, and combining the value in that spot with the value next to it, despite being, you know, separated by a comma. It also begins to combine the final value with the first value from the next set.

For Example:

CSV File:

```
0,0,0,104672
0,1,6,51971
0,1,36,80212
0,2,5,51972
0,2,13,51973
...
```

Program Output:

```
0
00
1046720
00
16
519710
136
...
```

I think the example probably does a better job describing what's going on than I did in words. It continues like that, displaying the wrong information until it reaches the end of the file.

My code is as follows:

```
static void Main()
{
    using(var fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\path\to\file.csv"))
    using(var read = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!read.EndOfStream)
        {
            int i = 0;
            var line = read.ReadLine();
            while (i < 4)
            {
                var values = line.Split(',');
                Console.Write(values[i]);
                Console.Read();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I got lost in my understanding of what the code should do and forgot to explain the goal here.

This program is made to take these values and rename a file from the 4th value (for example, 104672) to the first three values, separated by dashes (ex. 0-0-0). What I want from my output right now is to be able to see the program give me the values back, one at a time, so that I know when I go to rename the files, I'm not getting improper results.

EDIT 2: I also realize, a day later, that the answer I got was one of significance to making my program work, rather than actually discovering why I was getting the output I got. For those curious in the future, the answer is essentially that Console.Read(); is not a true pause, and causes more writes to happen upon key press than expected.

Comment: Why would you write your own code to parse the CSV?  There are plenty of libraries out there for this purpose if you just search.

Comment: And why do you wonder that `Console.Read()` is probably capturing two characters in subsequent calls each time you hit the return key? So the ultimate solution would be: switch to a system where the linebreak is represented by a single character and you will be fine ;)

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @rory.ap I am very used to rolling out my own code. This program will eventually be used to rename files based on these numbers.

Comment: I agree with @geek40. Maybe the `Console.Write(values[i])` followed by the `Console.Read()` is messing your output. Change the first with a `Console.WriteLine(values[i])` and move the `Conosole.Read()` out of inner `while`.

Comment: @Nino I would like to get back each individual number and store them in a variable for a few ticks before moving along and getting the next set.

Comment: @SMEAT, just FYI, rolling your own CSV parser may be a bit more involved than you think.  As a simple example, what if one of the fields contains a comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need those values for later use, why don't you put them into `List` for later... like this:

```
List<string[]> listOfValues = new List<string[]>();
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\csv.txt"))
    using (var read = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!read.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = read.ReadLine();
            listOfValues.Add(line.Split(','));                    
        }
    }
```

later, you can use data from list:

```
for (int i = 0; i<listOfValues.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("line number: {0}, contents: {1}", i + 1, string.Join(" ", listOfValues[i]));
}
```

which gives you

```
line number: 1, contents: 0 0 0 104672
line number: 2, contents: 0 1 6 51971
line number: 3, contents: 0 1 36 80212
line number: 4, contents: 0 2 5 51972
line number: 5, contents: 0 2 13 51973
```

Comment: I am not familiar with how C# handles this. Do I have to create a new object of a list class?

Comment: @SMEAT sorry, i forgot to make instance of List. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A more clear and easy-to-understand approach would be:

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\path\to\file.csv"))
            {
                string currentLine;
                while((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] lineArr = line.Split(',');
                    foreach(string subLine in lineArr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(subline);
                    }
                    Console.Read(); // Awaits user input in order to proceed
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code what you think it's supposed to do.  Here is a version that will read each line, split it on the commas, and iterate through the values, printing each value.  After printing all the values for a line, it prints a new line.  Hopefully that's something like what you were trying to achieve.

```
static void Main()
{
    using(var fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\path\to\file.csv"))
    using(var read = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!read.EndOfStream)
        {
            int i = 0;
            var line = read.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');
            while (i < values.Length)
            {
                Console.Write(values[i]);
                //Console.Read();
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @rory.ap said, you have plenty of libraries to read CSV right out of the box. But event if you still want to do it on your own, it seems that it is taking a great effort on doing a simple task. Try this:

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/yourpath/yourfile.csv"))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] yourData = line.Split(',');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\path\to\file.csv"))    
    foreach (var segment in line.Split(','))        
        Console.WriteLine(segment);
```